# How can i read .txt file to long [] JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

I need to read file into the array `long[]`, so the result will be same as creating new instance:

```
long [] y = new long[] { 
   500, 300, 16800, 35200, 
   60000, 50000, 2200, 2200, 29500
};
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Which format will you use in the txt-File? CSV?

Comment: well, open a reader, read the text, split by the separator and parse each value into a long :-)

Comment: You need to be more precise about "what stops me" part. Do you want to know how to read text from file? Do you want to know how to convert text to long? Do you want to know how to store converted text in array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"));

        long[] values = new long[100];

        int i = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLong()) {

            values[i] = scanner.nextLong();
            i++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Generally it may be what OP needs but it is worth pointing that this solution will crash if there will be more than 100 numbers in file (and we assume that file contains only numbers). We should use List<Long> here and later (if we really need to) convert it to array.

Comment: Good observation @Pshemo, this one only works if you can assume there is a maximum number of longs in the file.

Comment: @DeiAndrei I think that this is a really bad practice.
You shouldn't assume max number of input data, especially as an auxillary value.

Answer (score 0):

Try. Ugly, but should work

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt")); 
String[] numbersStrings = scanner.readLine().split(" "); 
long[] numbers = new long[numbersStrings.length]; 
for (int i = 0; i < numbersStrings.length; i++) {
       numbers[i] = Long.parseLong(numbersStrings[i]); 
}
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), a [`List<Long>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and a pair of loops (one to read the `long`(s) into a `List` then a second to convert the `List` to an array) with something like -

```
public static long[] readFile(String filePath) {
    List<Long> al = new ArrayList<Long>();
    File f = new File(filePath);
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try  {
        scanner = new Scanner(f);
        while (scanner.hasNextLong()) {
            al.add(scanner.nextLong());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
    long[] ret = new long[al.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        ret[i] = al.get(i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the previous answer as a base:

```
try (Scanner scanner : new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt")) {
  List<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
  while (scanner.hasNextLong()) {
    numbers.add(scanner.nextLong());
  }
  Long[] value = numbers.toArray(new Long[numbers.size()]);

  // or:
  long[] values = new long[numbers.size()];
  int i = 0;
  for (Long n : numbers) {
    values[i] = n;
    ++i;
  }

}
```

- The [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is used to close the Scanner, and the file, when you're done reading it.
- [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is a class that can read various thing, and among all, it can read `Long`.
- We need to store the values inside an `ArrayList` because we don't know the amount of number there are in the file.

Converting the `ArrayList` is then a little tricky:

- With auto boxing `Long` can be converted to `long` (and `long` to `Long`), but that don't work for arrays: `Long[]` is not a `long[]`.
- The first form use the toArray method, which return an array of `Long`.
- The second form create an array of `long[]` and fill it with the numbers from the list using a for-each.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner might be a bit slow for larger inputs. I recommend tokenizer
Also, this will be more memory effective since we're not allocating any extra Object (wrappers for primitives), and no extra temporary data structure (except tokenizer internals)

```
// Read the file into the string.
// WARNING: This will throw OutOfMemoryException on very large files 
// To handle large file you will need to wrap the file into a buffer and read it partially.
// Also this method is present only in Java 7+ . If you're on 6, just use regular file reading
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
String str = new String(fileContent, encoding);

// The second parameter is the delimiter. If your data is separated by space, this will work. 
// Otherwise (ex. by comma - ,) you will need to supply it here
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str," ");

long[] values = new long[tokenizer.countTokens()];

int idx = 0;
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
  values[idx++] = Long.parseLong(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```